# Зависимость option от input

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется простой калькулятор
как назначит на разный тип дизайна свой тариф который будет выводится в вариантах и будет разным при количествах
Например при Простой дизайн сайта 1 вариант стоит 100р, а Сложный 300.
В простом дизайне при увеличении на 1 в графе "Кол-во вариантов:" должно прибавится +10р, в сложном +20,  интр магазин +50р
Изначально переработка выключена, и при увеличении на 1 нужно увеличить на 500р

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Калькулятор на JavaScript</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
       /*
        * Функция подсчета стоимости услуг на создания дизайна сайта
        */
        function calc() {
            //получаем ссылку на элемент Select (Тип дизайна)
            var type_design = document.getElementById("type_design");
            //получаем ссылку на чекбокс (Требуется верстка?)
            var is_html = document.getElementById("is_html");
            //получаем ссылку на элемент input (Кол-во вариантов)
            var count = document.getElementById("count");
            //получаем ссылку на элемент span, в него будем писать стоимость дизайна
            var result = document.getElementById("result"); 
 
            var price = 0;
            price += parseInt(type_design.options[type_design.selectedIndex].value);
            price += (is_html.checked == true) ? parseInt(is_html.value) : 0;
            price = parseInt(count.value) * price;
 
            result.innerHTML = price;
        }
 
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <b>Тип дизайна:</b><br/>
        <select onchange="calc()" id="type_design">
            <option value="0">Выбрать</option>
            <option value="100">Простой дизайн сайта</option>
            <option value="300">Сложный дизайн сайта</option>
            <option value="500">Дизайн интернет-магазина</option>
        </select><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" onchange="calc()" value="3000" id="is_html" />
        <label for="is_html">Требуется верстка?</label>
        <br/>
        Кол-во вариантов: <input type="text" id="count" value="1" onchange="calc()" />
        <div> 0 р/час</div> <p>здесь указывать нормочас относительно типа дизайна</p>
        
         Переработка: <input type="text" id="count" value="0" onchange="calc()" />
         
        <p>переработка на 1 час стоит 500р</p>
        
        <div>Стоимость дизайна сайта: <span id="result">0</span> руб.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Что нужно реализовать, что бы при выборе "Дизайна" отображался тариф в блоке  0 р/час, и при увеличении Кол-во вариантов: увеличивалась конечная цена согласно тарифу, А также переработка, по дефолту 0, при увеличении количества +500р

Comment: и в чем проблема?

Comment: Что нужно, что бы при выборе "Дизайна" отображался тариф в блоке <div> 0 р/час</div>, и при увеличении Кол-во вариантов: увеличивалась конечная цена согласно тарифу, А также переработка, по дефолту 0, при увеличении количества +500р

Comment: В простом дизайне при увеличении на 1 должно прибавится +10р, в сложном 20,  интр магазин 50р